# SQLite3 - unrecognized token

Tags: sqlite3

Olá! Podem me ajudar?

Já testei de vários modos, porém não consegui entender.

Com até 3 variáveis essa forma funciona, porém com 7 variáveis apresenta o erro na imagem abaixo.

Estou a mais de 6 horas preso nesse problema.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3

a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7 = "a","b","c","d","e","f","g"


def save(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('5w2h.db')
    bd = conn.cursor()
    bd.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 5w2h (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        who TEXT, 
        where TEXT, 
        when TEXT, 
        what TEXT, 
        why TEXT, 
        how TEXT, 
        how_much TEXT);""")

    bd.execute("""INSERT INTO 5w2h (who, where, when, what, why, how, how_much) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);""", (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


save(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está criando uma tabela que começa com um número, **5w2h**, além de que o nome de um dos campos, **where**, é palavra reservada dentro do SQL. Uma forma de solucionar é colocar colocá-los todos entre aspas:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "5w2h" ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
NOT NULL, "who" TEXT, "where" TEXT, "when" TEXT, "what" TEXT, "why" TEXT,
"how" TEXT, "how_much" TEXT);
```

O problema é que você terá sempre que lembrar de continuar colocando os nomes entre aspas a cada comando, veja:

Sem aspas/apóstrofos (erro com o nome da tabela)

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO 5w2h (who, where, when, what, why, how, how_much) VALUES
("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
Error: unrecognized token: "5w2h"
```

Nome da tabela entre aspas (erro com o `where` fora do lugar)

```
INSERT INTO "5w2h" (who, where, when, what, why, how, how_much) VALUES
("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
Error: near "where": syntax error
```

Todos os nomes entre aspas (comando executado com sucesso)

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO "5w2h" ("who", "where", "when", "what", "why", "how",
"how_much") VALUES ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");
```

A melhor forma de solucionar o problema é não usá-los (tabelas e campos começados com números ou palavras reservadas) ou então prefixá-los com alguma coisa, tipo `table_5w2h`, `text_where` etc.

Comment: Giovanni Nunes, agradeço sua atenção e disponibilidade em ajudar. Eu vou testar logo que eu estiver em frente ao PC. Obrigado.